# API architecture - what to include

Tags: api, rest, restful-architecture, api-design

I am building a RESTful api for a project at the moment, the API will used for a web application, a mobile application and maybe eventually a desktop application.

There are a few instances where emails need to be sent to notify the user of an event that has happened within the application. What I am not sure of is where to does a an APIs job finish, should the API be responsible for sending the emails, or should the application send the emails based on what response comes from the API?

Basically what I am asking is where does an APIs job start and finish, is an APIs job just getting date from point A to point B? Or can it deeper capabilities?

Answer (score 2):

It's a common mistake that many developers are still making. An API is just an interface through which you expose your underlying system to be accessed by other systems. How you expose your system depends on what functionalities you want to be visible to the external world. Moreover, your business logic should be entirely on your backend rather than spread over your mobile/web applications.

Having said that, my answer is yes! Don't think of it as "my API is sending emails". Think of it as "my MAIN SYSTEM is sending emails". Whether you want to expose this email functionality through your API or not is another completely different thing.